# Box overlaying navigation element

Tags: html, css

How do I make a header similar to the picture below? I got stuck on the part with the logo and the navigation bar. How can I make a div (logo) to break up the navigation bar (grey/black line) like that? The navigation bar and slideshow should be full screen width (responsive), the content area is 1200px in width. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syeL5x2t/20/

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="inside">
        <div id="logo"><a href="" title=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />test</a></div>
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hVq.png)

Comment: You will need to post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Please provide us with a simplified jsfiddle ( `<>` button) of your code. Otherwise it's pretty difficult to help you.

Comment: Hope this works? Never done a jsfiddle before: https://jsfiddle.net/syeL5x2t/20/

Answer (score 0):

I would add 3 divs for the header:
One for the grey area, one for the logo and one for the black Area.

Then you give each div a fixed position and a specific width.

I hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want, but here's an example of what I've come up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/lenochka/syeL5x2t/39/

I've used `display: flex` and added couple of divs in there and removed quite a lot of your css.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is not what I was looking for. The content area (.inside) should be 100% (max-width 1200px). The areas left of the logo and right of navigation menu3 should be flexible to make it fullscreen.